# get_tags() return an empty array after added tags with wp_insert_term()

Tags: database, tags, array, terms

I added some Tags programmatically with [wp_insert_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term), and later I call [get_tags()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) to use them, but it returns an empty array, although they are inserted in the database.

Here is my code:

install.php

```
$tags = array(
    array('name' => 'Beachfront Escapes', 'slug' => 'beachfront-escapes'),
    array('name' => 'Group Holidays', 'slug' => 'group-holidays'),
    array('name' => 'City Breaks', 'slug' => 'city-breaks')
);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (!term_exists($tag['name'], 'post_tag')) {
        wp_insert_term($tag['name'], 'post_tag', array('slug' => $tag['slug']));
    }
}
```

display.php

```
$tags = get_tags();
var_dump($tags); // empty array()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do the tags have any posts assigned to them? [Default arguments for `get_tags`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags#Parameters) hides empty terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Milo I could fix it. The problem was, that the tags were not assigned to any post.

display.php

```
$tags = get_tags(array('hide_empty' => false));
```

The `hide_empty` param do the trick.